# How can I make paragraphs in flutter in a text widget?

Tags: flutter

How can I make paragraphs in flutter in a text widget?  Can't I use like android java string file in flutter?

Comment: yes, you can use a string file as a source of your text data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in different ways in Flutter.
I suggest two options:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(children: [
                TextSpan(text: 'Text 2'),
                TextSpan(text: 'Text 2'),
              ]),
            ),
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(children: [
                TextSpan(text: 'Text 3'),
                TextSpan(text: 'Text 4'),
              ]),
            ),
            Text('Line 1\nLine 2'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

1. RichText
2. Put \n in your text.

Comment: For my Flutter 3.19 app, the TextSpan()s appear one after other in a horizontal line. Also between two RichText()s there is no space? I had to use SizedBox to add some space? However, the newline '\n' character in Text() does add some space between the two Line1 and Line2. I don't think that's supposed to happen?