# Adding Column as child to Container in flutter is not working. How to solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code for contacts page which renders fine:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ContactsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContactsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Contacts Page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when I change the container contents with the following nothing gets displayed in the screen:

```
return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(children: [
                TextSpan(text: "Text 2"),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

UPDATE 01:
The ContactsPage object is assigned to body in Scaffold of other class extending stateful widget.

I was looking at this [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufer4QTFTO8) and tried to create an about page, but failed. Also this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133715/how-can-i-make-paragraphs-in-flutter-in-a-text-widget).

Pastebin links:

1. [main.dart](https://pastebin.com/aPLpCpG0)
2. contacts.dart (first code in the question above)
3. dashboard.dart and events.dart are very similar to contacts.dart only minor changes.
4. about.dart which I'm trying to modify to add information into.

What am I coding wrong here?

Comment: Can you use `Scaffold` as the parent of `Container` ?

Comment: @Zahra No nothing displays with Scaffold either.

Comment: can you share a dartpad link

Comment: Create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and share  https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/wiki/Sharing-guide

Comment: it is possible something wrong with theme, can you provide textStyle

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh, I added pastebin instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the Container in Scaffold.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                children: [
                   TextSpan(text: "Text 2"),
                 ],
               ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
 );
```

Comment: I tried wrapping in scaffold but that did not work for my case. This stateless class object gets assigned to the body: in another Scaffold. I updated my question.

Comment: can you add minimal code to replicate the issue you are facing?

Comment: There are no error messages, there is top bar but nothing beneath. Sorry I can't use the exact terms I should be using, new to the language.

Comment: try playing with the style of the TextSpan. Try setting the text color as black. Updated the answer